# search lat/log from Adress using GMMap in Delphi

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I wanted just and simply hit a normal full address in edit box and get it's position (lat/log) and mark it in the map. I don't have any clue about getting latitude and longitude from adress , I was searching in GMMap properties , I could not see it at all. Could you please a help on that ?

Thanks

Comment: For forward (as well as reverse) geocoding use the `TGMGeoCode` component from GMLib.

Comment: I m using TGMGeoCode and TGMMarker too but could not see where is the propertie(s) , any idea ? do you have an sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a lat/lng from an address, you need to geocode it. To do that, put a TGMGeocode component, link it with the TGMMap and call Geocode method with the address.

A geocodification can return 1 or more results (until 10 with standard Google access). For example, if you geocode "Andorra" you will get 2 results, Andorra a country and Andorra a city from Spain. For this reason, the result of geocodification is an array (GeoResult). You can iterate it with Count property.

To know the lat/lng from a GeoResult, you need to read TGMGeocode[i].Geometry.Location property or TGMGeocode.GeoResult[i].Geometry.Location property (is the same)